# Why some UIKit references are classes and others are protocols? Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, delegation

Why some user interface objects needs protocols and delegation to control them?

For example, in `tableView` , to add row ..
Why it is not possible to write..

```
UItableviem.numberOfRawInSections = 3
```

Exactly like when we try to specify buttons properties for example.

Comment: Please don't just vote down! Give me an answer or a reference that can help me.

Comment: Because that's the way Apple designed it.  Other than that the question is way too broad and the answer is way too opinion-based for discussion here.